# Получить data-marker-id объекта с помощью jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, click

```
<a href=""  data-marker-id="174">
 <div>
  <div>
     <div>
        <div class="block"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</a>


     $('.block').on('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert('click');
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам просто получить `data-marker-id` то так:

```
elem.getAttribute('attribute');
```

Если так на вашем примере то как-то так:

```
$('.block').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let num = this.closest('a[data-marker-id]').getAttribute('data-marker-id');
    console.log(num);
    //alert('click');
 });
```